# get first digit in a string in python

Tags: python, string, match

this is my first day with python and i'm stuck. I have a file which content looks like this:

- Declaration //skip
- foo bar //shown as option
- Labels //skip
- 1 foo
- 2 foo
- 3 bar
- 4 foo bar
- ...
- 23546477 bar bar bar bar foo

If the user choose foo, I just want to return 1,2, 4 and 23546477 and write in a file:

- Target 1
- Target 2
- Target 4
- Target 23546477

This is what I have come up so far:

```
import sys
import re

def merge():

   if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    labfile = sys.argv[1]
    f = open(labfile, 'r')
    f.readline()
    string = f.readline()
    print "Possible Target States:"
    print string
    var = raw_input("Choose Target States: ")
    print "you entered ", var
    f.readline()
    words = var.split()
    for line in f.readlines():
      for word in words:
        if word in line:
          m = re.match("\d+", line)
          print m
          //get the first number and store it in a list or an array or something else

    f.close()

merge()
```

unfortunately it is not working - I see lines like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fce496c0100>` instead of the output I want.

Comment: What isn't working?  Is it raising an exception?  What do you get?

Comment: try re.find instead of re.match

Comment: *How* is it not working? Does it throw an exception? Produce the wrong result? Burst through the door wearing a red cape and shout "No one expects the Spanish Inquisition!"?

Comment: Rather than saying "it is not working" and assuming people will run your code, paste output, error messages, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: i get <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fce496c0100>
from print m...and I was hopening to get a number

Comment: alright alright sry for not mentioning what the output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do (at least):

```
if m:  #only execute this if a match was found
   print m.group()  #m.group() is the portion of the string that matches your regex.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) - `re.match` returns a Match object, which is what you're seeing.  [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) will give you a list of strings matching a pattern in a given line.

To get just the first, you *do* want to use Match objects, but you want [`re.search` not `re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) and then you need to call `m.group()` to get the matched string out of the Match object.